# Azure convert blob to file

Tags: azure, blob

Some large disks containing hundreds of 30GB tar files have been prepared and ready to ship.

The disks have been prepared as BLOB using the WAImportExport tool.
The Azure share is expecting files.
Ideally we don't want to redo the disks as FILE instead of BLOB. Are we able to upload as BLOBs to one storage area and extract the millions of files from the tarballs to a FILE storage area without writing code?

Thanks

Kevin

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. What do you mean they're prepared as BLOB? Are you talking about your content being put into Azure Storage blobs? A database BLOB column? Something else? Also, not clear about "FILE storage area." Please edit to be more specific.

Comment: Also - you mention 'disks' - does this imply you've uploaded .vhd's to Azure blobs?

Comment: These are physical disks to be shipped to the MS datacenter. The disks contain tar files in a bitlocker'd NTFS volume that was prepared with the WAImportExport tool. The manifest that was generated uses the term blob. The Azure Portal was set up by another company and is expecting files (under storage there are distinctly FILE SERVICE and BLOB SERVICE headings with options underneath. Not entirely sure we have a problem: we need to be untarring those files which have deep file paths to a file - type system in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

azcopy will definitely do it and has been tested. We were able to move files from blobs to files using the CLI in Azure with the azcopy command.

### The information provided below was proven not to be true.

Microsoft Partner told me yesterday there is no realistic way to convert Blobs to Files in the above-mentioned scenario. 
Essentially, it is important to select either WAImportExport.exe Version 1 for BLOBS or WAImportExport.exe Version 2 for files. Information on this can be found at [this location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-import-export-service).

The mistake was easily made and done so by a number of people here: the link to the tool sent was to the binary version 1. Search results tended to direct users to version 1 but version 2 only appears only after deeper dig. Version 2 - seems to be an afterthought my Microsoft when they added the Files option to Azure. It's a pity they didn't use different binary names or build a switch into version 2 to do both and delete the version 1 offering.